# PosgreSQL join table as array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, group-by

I have a table which is called - questions:

```
 id |   type   | test_id |              text               
----+----------+---------+---------------------------------
  1 | single   |       1 | What you can do?
  2 | multiple |       2 | What he can do?
  3 | anything |       3 | What I can do?
  5 | multiple |       1 | Are you a man?
  8 | anything |       3 | 5
  6 | anything |       1 | What are you going to do today?
```

Also I have a table called - answers:

```
 id | question_id |    answer     | is_right_answer 
----+-------------+---------------+-----------------
  1 |           1 | Everything    | t
  2 |           1 | Nothing       | f
  3 |           1 | That depends  | f
  4 |           2 | Everything    | f
  5 |           2 | Nothing       | t
  6 |           2 | That depends  | t
  7 |           3 | Everything    | t
  8 |           3 | Nothing       | t
  9 |           3 | That depends  | t
```

I want to select by id from questions table and get smth like this:

```
 {
    id: 1,
    type: 'single',
    text: 'What you can do?',
    test_id: '1',
    answers: [{id: 1, question_id: 1, answer: 'Everything', is_right_answer: t}, {id: 12 question_id: 1, answer: 'Nothing', is_right_answer: f}]
  },
```

So, I want to get all related answers to the exact question as an array.

How can I do that in postgreSQL?

Comment: Please show us the content that you expect in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want a JSON(B) output, you can do this with `row_to_jsonb()` and `jsonb_agg()`:

```
select 
    q.*,
    (select jsonb_agg(row_to_json(a)) from answers a where a.question_id = q.id) answers
from questions q
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=95d353dd3cf4b74efe89c6e4cd4e8088)**:

```
id | type     | test_id | text                            | answers                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
-: | :------- | ------: | :------------------------------ | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | single   |       1 | What you can do?                | [{"id": "1", "answer": "Everything", "question_id": 1, "is_right_answer": true}, {"id": "2", "answer": "Nothing", "question_id": 1, "is_right_answer": false}, {"id": "3", "answer": "That depends", "question_id": 1, "is_right_answer": false}]
 2 | multiple |       2 | What he can do?                 | [{"id": "4", "answer": "Everything", "question_id": 2, "is_right_answer": false}, {"id": "5", "answer": "Nothing", "question_id": 2, "is_right_answer": true}, {"id": "6", "answer": "That depends", "question_id": 2, "is_right_answer": true}] 
 3 | anything |       3 | What I can do?                  | [{"id": "7", "answer": "Everything", "question_id": 3, "is_right_answer": true}, {"id": "8", "answer": "Nothing", "question_id": 3, "is_right_answer": true}, {"id": "9", "answer": "That depends", "question_id": 3, "is_right_answer": true}]  
 5 | multiple |       1 | Are you a man?                  | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 6 | anything |       1 | What are you going to do today? | null                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 8 | anything |       3 | 5                               | null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_agg()`:

```
select q.*,
       (select array_agg(a.answer)
        from answers a
        where a.question_id = q.id
       ) as answers
from questions q;
```

Comment: You managed to answer the previous question I asked. I would accept it anyways) Thanks a lot)